# "I have had this book for 10 years' or "I have this book for 10 years"

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions

Good day.

Can I say "I have had this book for 10 years" if I want to say that I got the book 10 years ago and I have this book right now and i will have it in the future?

Or should I say "I have this book for 10 years"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"I have had this book for 10 years" is correct. This describes how long you have possessed the book.

It does not describe the future. If you would like to also say that you intend to keep the book and will still have it in the future then you need to state that separately.

Comment: Does it mean that "I have this book for 10 years" is incorrect? If it is correct where I can use it and what does it describe?

Comment: Yes, "I have this book for 10 years," is incorrect. "I have this book," is present tense and does not work with a time period.